# PL/SQL CLOB to Snowflake Data Warehouse VARCHAR

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, clob, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working with an Oracle 12c database which has a long character (CLOB) field.  It needs to be loaded into a Snowflake data warehouse, which has no equivalent of CLOB (it simply has VARCHAR to be used for all string fields).

While we can CAST the CLOB column to VARCHAR2 just fine, it contains values longer than 4000 characters, which of course returns an error that the value is too long for its data type.

I searched for alternatives to using CAST and did find other methods.  Example:

```
select dbms_lob.substr(ha.log,8000,1) log
from ha
```

When I execute that through Oracle SQL Developer, it returns the results as expected.  However, when trying to load to the Snowflake data warehouse using our ETL application (which uses the Oracle JDBC Thin driver, 12.2.0.1), Oracle returns the following errors:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1

I was unable to find the cause, but I found one other solution, which is to break up the CLOB into pieces like so:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(ha.log,0,3999)) log
FROM ha
```

And that returns yet another error:

ORA-64203: Destination buffer too small to hold CLOB data after character set conversion.

That error seems to indicate that the destination can't store the value due to it being too large, but that shouldn't be the case.  Snowflake VARCHAR fields can store very large amounts of data (similar to VARCHAR(MAX) in SQL Server).

I suspect there might be some setting in the JDBC driver related to buffer size that needs to be adjusted, but am not familiar with how to do so.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems it's an Oracle-side error, so can't help here... Snowflake supports strings up to 16MB...

Comment: I didn't find the cause of these errors, so I'll leave this open, but I can say that I found a workaround.  It was as simple as loading the CLOB field into a Snowflake VARCHAR field directly, no conversion required.

Comment: It's likely the errors your ETL platform is reporting are inside Oracle before hitting the JDBC driver; the JDBC driver is just passing them through. Since you found a way to load the data it may no longer be relevant. If you're curious, you could try running the PLSQL your ETL platform is writing for that conversion directly in Oracle to see what's happening.